# how do I detect multiple kye presses in vb

Tags: vb.net

I want to press three keys at the same time and output another eg. press a, b, c and output d (this needs to run in the background and send the output to the current foreground program - like word or chrome or ...) I have visual studio 2019 on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of a boolean that becomes true when you press a key down (KeyDown event) and becomes false when you release it (KeyUp event). Three of these booleans will tell if you have 3 keys simultaneously held.

Comment: how will that tell me which keys I have down. I'm creating a one-hand full range keyboard using just the keypad and arrow keys

Comment: . Would I need a boolean variable for each of the keys I may use (say 10 keys) and then run through a case statement to determine which combinations are down (104 possible combinations) and what to output in each time?